# Database to wrapper-classes or direct connectivity to database for time-series simulation application?

Tags: python, database, matlab, oop, time-series

I am writing an application that uses historical time series data to perform simulations.

Is it better for application to load the data from the database into local data wrapper classes before executing the main loop (up to 30 years day by day) or connect to the database each day to pull the required data?

Which is more elegant and efficient?

Comment: The efficiency depends on how much data you have per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For current computers 30 years of day by day data amounts to almost nothing if your dayly data remains below say 10kB. Since your simulation may need efficient retrieval, especially if it combines data from different dates, I'd read all the data in memory in one query and then start processing.

What is considered elegant is changing. Quite some years ago loading everything in to memory would have been considered a cardinal sin. Nowadays in-memory databases are common. Since databases in general offer set-level access (especially when queried by SQL, which you probably use) it would be quite inefficient to retrieve data item by item in a loop (although your database may be clever enough to cache things).